# Ubuntu - Microsoft SQLCMD - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, sqlserver

So, I have this issue that I can't connect to an MS SQL Server from an Ubuntu VM.

The situation:

- One Windows Server with multiple MS SQL Instances
- Two Ubuntu 20.04 LTS VMs

One of the two Ubuntu VMs was perfectly able to connect to the SQL server using

```
sqlcmd -S sqserver.example.com\\instance1 -U sql.serviceaccount -P 'mypassword'
```

but on the other server (which is very similar in setup, same network, ubuntu version etc) I get the following error

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : MAX_PROVS: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. .
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

So, I began to trouble shoot on VM2:

- I can ping sqserver.example.com
- Using `nc` I can connect to the open port of the SQL instance (something like port 56042)
- Removed every firewall rule and allowed all traffic using iptables`
- Rebooted the VM
- Checked the IP config (which is like the VM1 where it does work, only the IP address is one higher, 172.16.1.12 instead of 172.16.1.11).
- Checked the ARP tables on both ends, making sure there was nothing funky there (no duplicate IPs or something)

On the SQL side:

- Double checked that the SQL Browser Service was running (and restarted it)
- Restarted the SQL instance`
- Checked if there was a Windows Firewall (there isn't one enabled).

Having done all that I gave up and reinstalled Ubuntu on VM2. Default server install, nothing special. Installed the [Microsoft SQL tools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver16#ubuntu) on the same manner as before (and as on the VM01).

Of course I sort of hoped it would work but to my suprise and chagerin I get the following:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : MAX_PROVS: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. .
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
r
```

Exactly the same error.

Besides that I can ping the SQL server I can also download files from a webserver on that machine using `curl` to the VM02.

I am a bit out of options. The SQL server is reachable by another Linux machine and several Windows machines.

---

Update:

Using this [piece of Python script](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlserverport) I discovered I just don't get a answer from the SQL browsers service.

On VM1 I get the following response:

```
Instance 172.16.1.123\instance1 is listening on port 56044.
```

On VM2 I get the following response:

```
No response from the SQL Browser service. Verify that the service is available on 172.16.1.123 and \instance1 is a valid instance name on it.
```

Of course, both running with the same script.

---

Update:

So I can connect  to a specific instance using

```
sqlcmd -S tcp:sqlserver.example.com,56040 -U sqlaccount
```

So this work, still very strange but I'll take it for the moment.

Comment: Followed this Microsoft article (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/connect/using-portqrytool-sqlserver) to troubleshoot connection issues. But from a Windows machine all is ok, as I suspected because I can connect to the SQL instance.

Comment: Also tried ````sqlcmd -S tcp:sqserver.example.com\\instance1 -U sql.serviceaccount -P 'mypassword'
````
With an explicit TCP connection. No change.

Comment: Are these clients all trying to connect to the same SQL Server? Specifically I ask this to rule out configuration setting differences within SQL Server such as the one allowing remote connections, or the part that manages user accounts.

Comment: Do you have the same odbcinst file on each Ubuntu client? I think for SQL Server there's another file you need to set up, too, but it's been a while since I last set up something like this

Comment: Yes, the clients are connecting to the same SQL server (and are resolving to the same IP address). I copy and pasted a working `sqlcmd` command from one to the other. 

I have installed the `sqlcmd` the same way on both machines, haven't touched a config file.